# Grails / Spock testing .. unexpected error thrown

Tags: grails, testing, spock

Using spock to unit test a comand object  ..  I have a line in the command object  ..

some code  ..

```
   } else { 
      if ((val && obj.part) && obj.transactionType.transactionIsATransfer()) { 
         println "obj.part .. class is ${obj.part.getClass()} .. serial is    ${val.getClass()}" 
         if(! isAValidPartSerialCombo(obj.part,val))  <-- line 79  
             return 'com.myStuff.TransactionDetailCommand.serialReference.not.for.part' 
    } 
.. 

def isAValidPartSerialCombo {part, serialReference -> 
        return InventoryMaster.hasPartandSerial(part,serialReference) 
}
```

I have a unit test  where I mock out the dependency

```
def obj = new TransactionDetailCommand(transactionType: new TransactionType(type: 'Transfer', requireSerial: true), 
              serialReference: 'AAA', part: new Part(partNumber: 'AAA')) 

      obj.metaClass.isAValidPartSerialCombo = {a,b -> false}

  and: "we try to validate the transaction " 
      obj.validate() 

  then: "we get an error on the transaction for the 'serialReference' property" 
      obj.errors['serialReference']
```

which is giving me an error ..

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class 
        at com.vantec.TransactionDetailCommand._clinit__closure1_closure7(TransactionDetailCommand.groovy:90) 
        at grails.test.MockUtils.addValidateMethod_closure87_closure114(MockUtils.groovy:1035) 
        at grails.test.MockUtils.addValidateMethod_closure87(MockUtils.groovy:1031) 
        at grails.test.MockUtils.addValidateMethod_closure88(MockUtils.groovy:1065) 
        at com.myStuff.transaction.TransactionDetailCommandSpec.Ensure that for issues / transfer transactions then serial/part numbers are required to match .. (TransactionDetailCommandSpec.groovy:79)
```

However if I create a separate dummy test  it works without a problem ..

```
def "A simple test  .. "(){ 
    when: 
        def obj = new TransactionDetailCommand() 
        obj.metaClass.isAValidPartSerialCombo = {a,b -> false} 

    then: 'we get a false ..' 
        !obj.isAValidPartSerialCombo(new Part(),"AAA") 
}
```

Can anyone shed any light ??

Thanks

Complete test ...

```
  def "Ensure that for issues / transfer transactions then serial/part numbers are required to match .. "(){

          when: "The transaction type indicates a transfer and we supply a serial number and a part .."

              def obj = new TransactionDetailCommand(transactionType: new TransactionType(type: 'Transfer', requireSerial: true),
                      serialReference: '12345', part: new Part(partNumber: 'PartA'))

              obj.metaClass.isAValidPartSerialCombo = {a,b -> false}

          and: "we try to validate the transaction "
              obj.validate()

          then: "we get an error on the transaction for the 'serialReference' property"
              obj.errors['serialReference']

          and: "the error is the correct one .."
              'com.myStuff.TransactionDetailCommand.serialReference.not.for.part' == obj.errors['serialReference']

    }
```

and the constraint i'm testing  ..

```
serialReference nullable: true, validator: { val, obj ->

           println "One .. "
           if ((val == null || val.toString().isEmpty()) && obj.transactionType.requireSerial) {
                 println "Two .. "
                return 'com.myStuff.TransactionDetailCommand.serialReference.required'
            } else {
                 println "Three .. "
                if ((val && obj.part) && obj.transactionType.transactionIsATransfer()) {
                    println "Four ..."
                    if(! isAValidPartSerialCombo(obj.part, val)){
                        println("Five .. ")
                        return  'com.myStuff.TransactionDetailCommand.serialReference.not.for.part'
                    }
                }
            }

            return 'oops'
        }



 def isAValidPartSerialCombo = {part, serialReference ->
        println "Six .."
        // return InventoryMaster.hasPartandSerial(part,serialReference)
        return true
    }
```

The println's are just so I can see where the code goes ..

Comment: Which line is the 79 in TransactionDetailCommandSpec.groovy?

Comment: Sorry  ..  It's the obj.validate() .. which fails on the line i've marked as 79 in the first block of code  ..

Comment: Can you make `isAValidPartSerialCombo` **static** (since validator is in static context) and use `obj.metaClass.'static'.isAValidPartSerialCombo`? I would give that a try otherwise override the metaClass on the Class instead of the object.

Comment: I did that earlier and it didn't work (see below) .... until I changed the call in the validator routine from  if(! isAValidPartSerialCombo(obj.part, val)){ .. to  if(! obj.isAValidPartSerialCombo(obj.part, val)){ and now it's working !!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about it, but it would be worthy to give a try to mock the instance of obj after the creation of the instance

```
mockDomain(TransactionDetailCommand, [obj])
```

Comment: In my setup I already have ..`mockForConstraintsTests TransactionDetailCommand` .. Think i'll ttry and refactor the isAValidPartSerialCombo .. to a static and mock that .. I was getting an error with mockDomain  ..

Comment: Just for the failing method or all of them - there are quite a few !

Comment: The failing test method

Answer (score 0):

Try to organise in that way your test:

```
def "Ensure that for issues / transfer transactions then serial/part numbers are required to match .. "(){

      given: "The transaction type indicates a transfer and we supply a serial number and a part .."

          def obj = new TransactionDetailCommand(transactionType: new TransactionType(type: 'Transfer', requireSerial: true),
                  serialReference: '12345', part: new Part(partNumber: 'PartA'))

          obj.metaClass.isAValidPartSerialCombo = {a,b -> false}

      when: "we try to validate the transaction "
          obj.validate()

      then: "we get an error on the transaction for the 'serialReference' property"
          obj.errors['serialReference']

      and: "the error is the correct one .."
          'com.myStuff.TransactionDetailCommand.serialReference.not.for.part' == obj.errors['serialReference']

}
```

as the creation of the object and the metaprogramming are all set up actions.

Comment: Well i've seen and tried both approaches and i think it's down to personal preference really .. though in this case neither works - I get the same error  ..

Comment: I think it maybe something to do with this being a command object and it being defined with @TestFor(TransactionProcessingController) .. Though this is the only test i'm having the problem with - my other tests for the command object are working fine  ..